# readFileSync on STDIN vs readFile in node.js - char encoding?

Tags: node.js, fs, paperjs

I'm trying to read a file from STDIN, process it with [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) and return the results.

To get there I first tried to do it by reading in a file from the fs like this:

```
const Project = require('paper').Project
var fs = require('fs');
let p = new Project() 

fs.readFile( process.argv[2], function (err, data) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    
    p.importSVG(data.toString(), { onError: function(e){ console.log(e) } })
    console.log(p.exportSVG({ asString: true }));
});
```

which worked great.

Then I tried to get the data from STDIN (`cat foo_02.svg | node swiss.js` - yes, pointless use of cat, but just for the example) like this :

```
const Project = require('paper').Project
var fs = require('fs');
let p = new Project() 

const data = fs.readFileSync(process.stdin.fd).toString();

p.importSVG(data, { onError: function(e){ console.log(e) } })
console.log(p.exportSVG({ asString: true }));
```

which seem to mangle the data.

a `console.log(data)` added in shows this (truncated):

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0"
viewBox="0,0,0,0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="2074" height="748" fill="none">
      </rect>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"
  stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter"
  stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0"
  font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none"
  text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip-1)">
      <g fill="#f98673" font-family="sans-serif"
      font-weight="normal" font-size="12" text-anchor="start"></g>
      <path d="M1042.7,104.3c-1.6,1.3 -3.3,9.5 -2.8,14.1c0.3,3.6 4.7,10.3 7.2,11.1c1,0.3 3.6,2.7 5.8,5.3c9,10.7 12.1,14.7 12.1,15.9c0,0.7 0.6,1.6 1.3,2c0.8,0.4 2,2 2.8,3.4c2.3,4.2 7,11.3 8.3,12.4c0.7,0.5 1.8,1.9 2.6,3.1c2.1,2.9 10,12.3 12.8,14.9c1.2,1.2 2.2,2.7 2.2,3.2c0,0.5 3.6,4.4 8,8.8c4.4,4.3 9.9,10.5 12.1,13.8c4.5,6.6 14,18.7 17.9,22.8c2.8,2.9 3.9,4.2 12.3,14.7c3.1,4 8.2,10.3 11.2,14.1c3,3.7 5.5,7.3 5.5,7.8c0,0.5 0.8,1.8 1.8,2.9c0.9,1 3.1,3.8 4.9,6.2c3.1,4.4 11.4,13.8 18.8,21.7c6.4,6.7 9.3,10.4 14.4,17.9c4.2,6.3 9.1,15.6 9.1,17.2c0,0.3 1.4,2.5 3,4.9c3.7,5.4 3.7,6.7 0.3,11.3c-3.8,5 -21.8,27.1 -24.7,30.2c-1.3,1.4 -3.3,4.6 -4.6,7.2c-1.3,2.7 -2.7,4.8 -3,4.8c-0.4,0 -2,1.9 -3.5,4.3c-3.7,5.6 -8.1,11.1 -13,16.3c-7.8,8.2 -9.3,10.1 -21.8,25.9c-16,20.2 -15.9,20.1 -19.5,26c-1.6,2.8 -5.2,8.7 -8.1,13.3c-2.8,4.6 -5.1,8.7 -5.1,9c0,0.4 -1.8,2.9 -4,5.7c-2.2,2.7
```

while the final `console.log` results in (also truncated):

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0"
viewBox="0,0,0,0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-1">
      <rect x="0" y="0" transform="scale(0,0)" width="0" height="0"
      fill="none"></rect>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip-2">
      <rect x="-1037" y="-374" transform="scale(0,0)" width="2074"
      height="748" id="clip-1" fill="none"></rect>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"
  stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter"
  stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0"
  font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none"
  text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip-1)">
      <g>
        <g clip-path="url(#clip-2)">
          <g fill="#f98673" font-family="sans-serif"
          font-weight="normal" font-size="12" text-anchor="start">
          </g>
          <path d="M0,0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0zM0,0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v0v
```

Is there some implicit encoding going on here? working on linux/bash/node v10.19.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce it with another svg file like https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Speaker_Icon.svg.

Could you please link your svg file ?

I suggest you to try with the following code, as readFile on stdin could not work properly (https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7412)

```
const Project = require('paper').Project
var fs = require('fs');
let p = new Project() 

var chunks = [];
process.stdin
    .on("data", function(chunk) { chunks.push(chunk); })
    .on("end", function() {

        console.log(chunks.join("").toString());
        p.importSVG(chunks.join("").toString(), { onError: function(e){ console.log(e) } })
        console.log(p.exportSVG({ asString: true }));
    })
    .setEncoding("utf8");
```

Comment: Found the problem. It had nothing to do with SVG, or paper.js or STDIN - I can't provide details as I am too ashamed. Suffice it to say that I come from other programming languages where it's easier to remember to distinguish STDIN and STDERR, and this is my first node program. Thanks for the help though. I'll definitely test your solution, and it will come in handy in the future for sure